# Strange type inference behavior of Collections.emptyList() and/or Java generic methods?

Tags: java, generics, collections

This is `jdk1.7.0_04`.

I was attempting to use `Collections.emptyList()` rather than `new`ing up my own empty list in a conditional:

```
List<String> list = (anArray != null) ? Arrays.asList(anArray) : Collections.emptyList();
```

but get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types
        List<String> list = (anArray != null) ? Arrays.asList(anArray) : Collections.emptyList();
                                              ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    List<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
1 error
```

I was able to figure that I needed to change things to:

```
List<String> list = (anArray != null) ? Arrays.asList(anArray) : Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

But as part of working on this I encountered the bizarre (to me, anyways) situation that:

```
List<String> alwaysEmpty = Collections.emptyList();
```

compiles fine, but:

```
List<String> alwaysEmpty = (List<String>) Collections.emptyList();
```

gives the following compile error:

```
error: inconvertible types
        List<String> alwaysEmpty = (List<String>) Collections.emptyList();
                                                                       ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    List<Object>
```

What the heck??

Now I can understand that perhaps for some strange reason the use of the conditional operator is somehow blocking the type inference system from realizing that the type parameter for the `emptyList()` call should be `String` and so it needs to be explicitly specified.  But why does inserting a (admittedly redundant) cast mess things up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But why does inserting a (admittedly redundant) cast mess things up?

Because now the expression `Collections.emptyList()` in itself isn't the target of any assignment - so what type argument should be chosen? It's better just to specify the type argument:

```
// Redundant here, but just as an example
List<String> alwaysEmpty = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

It works the same for the conditional operator, too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {              
    List<String> list = (args != null)
        ? Arrays.asList(args) : Collections.<String>emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to accept Jon's answer, but also wanted to list as answer what someone just passed along to me about this outside of SO.  It is a link to a [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6721089) submitted to Sun/Oracle about this very thing.  The person evaluating the bug has a useful explanation of what is going on.  An excerpt:

> The submitter here seems to assume that the type of a conditional expression is the type on the LHS of an assigment (`List<String>` in this case). This is not true: as stated by the JLS, the type of a conditional expression:

"The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to `lub(T1, T2)` (§15.12.2.7). "

> 

It's important to understand why it's necessary to apply lub. Consider the following example:

```
class A {}
class B extends A{}
class C extends A{}
class Foo<X> 
Foo<? extends A> l = b ? new Foo<B>() : new Foo<C>()
```

> In this case we have that LHS is of type `Foo<? extends A>` while the RHS is of type `lub(Foo<B>, Foo<C>)`, that is `Foo<? extends B&C>`.